# Firebase 9 Web: how do I get download url for stored files?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get download urls for files in firebase storage.

```
const listRef = ref(storage, `photos/${route.params.id}`)

onMounted( async () => {
  await listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      res.items.forEach( (item) => {
        console.log(item._location)
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
})
```

I can just find path in the response object, which I can't use as an img src. How can I get a proper download url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you upload files you have to send request using function `getDownloadURL()` to a storage to get downloadURL. It is because of database are adding tokens to files so there is possibility to download files with no need to be logged in. Function `uploadBytes()` is write operation not read so for security reason you have separate function to get/read downloadURLs from storage.

Here you have function example in typescript. It upload array of files and return array of objects: `{ name: string, fullPath: string, downloadURL: string }`.

```js
async function uploadFiles(path: string, files: File[], id: string) {
    if (!files.length) return []
    const promises = []
    const data = []
    for (const item of files) {
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `${path}/${id}_${item.name}`)
        promises.push(uploadBytes(storageRef, item))
    }
    const uploadResults = await Promise.all(promises)
    const downloadURLs = []

    for (const item of uploadResults) {
        data.push({ fullPath: item.metadata.fullPath, downloadURL: '', name: '' })
        downloadURLs.push(getDownloadURL(item.ref))
    }

    const downloadURLsResult = await Promise.all(downloadURLs)

    for (var i = 0; i < downloadURLsResult.length; i++) {
        data[i].downloadURL = downloadURLsResult[i]
        data[i].name = files[i].name
    }

    return data
}
```